# Solidity: Unable to insert data into Struct

Tags: solidity

Trying to store a list of struct as a mapping but unable to insert data.

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.6;
```

contract PayTree {

```
address payable owner;
uint public expirationTime;
uint public wordValue;
bytes32 public root;
address[] private allMerchants;
uint public startTime;
bytes32[] usedTokens;

//Stores merchant information
struct merchant {
    address addr;
    uint numOfTokens;
    bytes32[] usedTokens;
}

//initialise state variables
constructor (uint _timeout, bytes32 _root, uint _wordValue) payable {
    owner = msg.sender;
    expirationTime = block.timestamp + _timeout;
    root = _root;
    startTime = block.timestamp;
    wordValue = _wordValue;
} 

//Maps Merchant ethereum address to merchant information
mapping (address => merchant) public Merchants;

function SetUpdateMerchants (bytes32 _token) private {
    var _merchant = merchant(msg.sender, numOfTokens++, usedTokens.push(_token));
    Merchants[msg.sender] = _merchant;
    allMerchants.push(_token)
}
```

Getting error:

> ParseError: Expected Primary expression var _merchant = merchant(msg.sender, numOfTokens++, usedTokens.push(_token)); ^-^

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `usedTokens.push(_token)` when creating a new `merchat` structure

Answer (score 0):

There're so many wrong stuff with this code:

1. `allMerchants` is array of addresses and you're trying to push `bytes32` variable to that array? Judging by the logic of the contract you want to save the initiator of the transaction here, so change that line to: `allMerchants.push(msg.sender);`
2. You're trying to create instance of struct `merchant`, but the value of `numOfTokens` is not defined
3. Why you're creating `var _merchant` and then saving that variable into `Merchants` mapping? This way you're creating a variable that will be used only once, you don't really need to create variable in such cases. You can simply do `Merchants[msg.sender] = merchant(<STRUCT_PARAMS>)`
4. Since solidity 0.6.0 the `.push()` method is returning nothing, it used to return the new array length in the past, but not anymore. So at the end you have to edit your method like:

```
function SetUpdateMerchants (bytes32 _token) private {
    usedTokens.push(_token);
    Merchants[msg.sender] = merchant(msg.sender, <SOME_UINT_VALUE>, usedTokens);
    allMerchants.push(msg.sender);
}
```